# How to disable Java Naming Conventions in xjc?

Tags: jaxb, xjc

For example sOmE_PROPerty in xsd must be sOmE_PROPerty in java class not someProperty.

I tried to use globalBindings enableJavaNamingConventions="false" but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Blaise Thanks for answer but even in your example it doesnt work. It is only in getter, i need here "protected String sOmEPROPerty". And it must not to change first letter to lower-case and letter after '_' to upper-case.

Comment: Solved by changing source code of jaxb in class com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl.NameConverter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by changing source code of jaxb in class com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl.NameConverter like this:

```java
public static final NameConverter standard = new Standard();

static class Standard extends NameUtil implements NameConverter {
    public String toClassName(String s) {
        return s;//toMixedCaseName(toWordList(s), true);
    }
    public String toVariableName(String s) {
        return s;//toMixedCaseName(toWordList(s), false);
    }
    public String toInterfaceName( String token ) {
        return token;//toClassName(token);
    }
    public String toPropertyName(String s) {
        String prop = s;//toClassName(s);
        // property name "Class" with collide with Object.getClass,
        // so escape this.
        if(prop.equals("Class"))
            prop = "Clazz";
        return prop;
    }
```

Comment: Did you implement this as a xjc extension, or did you literally modified its source code?

Comment: @RobertoBonvallet, you can implement NameConverter interface and then modify public static final NameConverter standard field with reflection.

Answer (score 12):

You will need to use `underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"` instead of `enableJavaNamingConventions="false"`:

**customer.xsd**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/customer" 
    xmlns="http://www.example.org/customer"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    <xsd:complexType name="customer">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="sOmE_PROPerty" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

**binding.xml**

A JAXB binding file is used to customize the schema to Java conversion:

```xml
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

```
xjc -d out -b binding.xml customer.xsd
```

**Customer**

The generated property names now include the underscore character:

```java
package org.example.customer;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "customer", propOrder = {
    "sOmEPROPerty"
})
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement(name = "sOmE_PROPerty", required = true)
    protected String sOmEPROPerty;

    public String getSOmE_PROPerty() {
        return sOmEPROPerty;
    }

    public void setSOmE_PROPerty(String value) {
        this.sOmEPROPerty = value;
    }

}
```

**Without Using binding.xml**

If you instead make the following XJC call:

```
xjc -d out -customer.xsd
```

You will see that the generated properties do not include the underscore:

```java
package org.example.customer;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "customer", propOrder = {
    "sOmEPROPerty"
})
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement(name = "sOmE_PROPerty", required = true)
    protected String sOmEPROPerty;

    public String getSOmEPROPerty() {
        return sOmEPROPerty;
    }

    public void setSOmEPROPerty(String value) {
        this.sOmEPROPerty = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but even in your example it doesnt work. It is only in getter, i need here "protected String sOmEPROPerty". And it must not to change first letter to lower-case and word after _ to upper-case.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did have the same problem, I solved the problem by means of your answer..

Comment: this works for xml but I have a slightly different problem...
I have <jxb:property name="_value"/> in my jsb which overrides one of the properties' name and this appears as "value" and not "_value".
The underscore in not overridden in this case..
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @icedek - Can you create a new question?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Thanks ... I just did at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821060/override-the-jaxb-property-name-using-a-xjb-preserving-the-underscores

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan however if it was SOmE_PROPerty it would convert it to sOmE_PROPerty. Is there a way to retain the first letter case?