# JAXB attributes using underscore

Tags: attributes, jaxb, underscore.js

I working on JAXB to using java object I am creating xml.But im using javaclass fields Like

qpack_id as attrubute it creating in xml file like qpackId

so how can i use _(underscore) in jaxB please guide me.

xml file should create bellow attibute

```
<qpack " qpack_id="MB0046_SET4" qpack_name="MB0046">
</qpack>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Starting from Java Classes**

You can use the `XmlAttribute` annotation to specify a name.

```java
@XmlAttribute(name="qpack_name")
public String getQPackName() {
    return qPackName;
}
```

**Starting from XML Schema**

If you are talking about generating Java classes from an XML schema and preserving the `_` character in the Java properties names see the answer below for a complete example:

- [How to disable Java Naming Conventions in xjc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267478/how-to-disable-java-naming-conventions-in-xjc/6271449#6271449)