# Override the JAXB property name using a xjb preserving the underscores

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

The custom xjb works great for overriding the names as desired however we lose the underscores in the names.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  version="2.1">
  <jxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"/>
   <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="foo.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='fooType']">
            <jxb:property name="value" />
        </jxb:bindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

As you can see for the above xjb the java code generated is

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "textType", propOrder = {
"value"
})
public class FooType {

@XmlMixed
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
protected List<Object> value;
......
 public List<Object> getValue() {
    if (value == null) {
        value = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    return this.value;
}
```

Now, once I change one line in the xjb above to:

```
 <jxb:property name="_value" />
```

All that changes in the java code is :

```
public List<Object> get_Value() {
    if (value == null) {
        value = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    return this.value;
}
```

Observed: **"value"**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "textType", propOrder = {
"value"
})
```

Desired: **"_value"**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "textType", propOrder = {
"_value"
})
```

Comment: I did some digging and I have a workaround which is crude.
The goal is to have the "value" appear as "_value" in my **json** and I use Gson to do that from the java objects(classes from jaxb).

Apparently, there is a 

    `@SerializedName("_value")`

which allows Gson to take care of the generated response with the desired name and if I add this line manually, and I get what I want.     Now, can this be done using the xjb so that I need NOT  manually add this line everytime I do a build? I tried playing with the annox plugin but that didn't seem to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following `propOrder` is fine since `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` is specified and the name of the field is `value` even though the property is called _Value (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder.html).

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "textType", propOrder = {
"value"
})
```

---

> The goal is to have the "value" appear as "_value" in my json

Your particular `_Value` property appears to be to be able to hold anything.  How do you want the contents to be rendered to JSON?

```
@XmlMixed
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
protected List<Object> value;
```

Comment: For now we fixed it to be a String. value is a String and in json it needs to appear as _value.
This can be done by adding an annotation @SerializedName("_value") (comment above). 
1)Is it possible to add an annotation to this property via xjb?
2)Is there a way to preserve the underscores in the property name?