# How to Disable Java naming conventions in JAXB XJC

Tags: java, jaxb, naming-conventions, xjc

I am using JAXB- XJC to generate POJO from XSD file. However I am unable to disable the java naming conventions. My example,

XSD Example

xsd:element name="cust_nbr" type="xsd:string"
                         minOccurs="0" default=""/

XJC is generating the variable name as cust_Nbr (With UpperCase "N") in the POJO. I want the variable to be "cust_nbr" as mentioned in XSD not "cust_Nbr".

I've tried using **underscoreBinding="asCharInWord" enableJavaNamingConventions="false"** options

and it didn't work. Can anyone tell me what other options are there to actually disable the java naming conventions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Java Naming Conventions in xjc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267478/how-to-disable-java-naming-conventions-in-xjc)

Comment: I checked that, but I don't want to modify the JAXB API. Is there any other way, I could do it.

Comment: Same problem here with `xjc` command line tool.