# xjc java classes generation, where fields have the same name as @XmlElement

Tags: java, xjc

Im creating java classes from a .xsd file using this [xjc](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html) script

```
for %%f in (*.xsd) do (
    xjc -no-header %%f
)
pause
```

it generates classes that look like this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AppData1", propOrder = {
    "appInstllCd",
    "appVrsn",
    "os",
    "osVrsn",
    "device"
})
public class AppData1 {

    @XmlElement(name = "AppInstllCd")
    protected String appInstllCd;
    @XmlElement(name = "AppVrsn")
    protected String appVrsn;
    @XmlElement(name = "OS")
    protected String os;
    @XmlElement(name = "OSVrsn")
    protected String osVrsn;
    @XmlElement(name = "Device")
    protected String device;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the appInstllCd property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getAppInstllCd() {
        return appInstllCd;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the appInstllCd property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setAppInstllCd(String value) {
        this.appInstllCd = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the appVrsn property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getAppVrsn() {
        return appVrsn;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the appVrsn property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setAppVrsn(String value) {
        this.appVrsn = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the os property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getOS() {
        return os;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the os property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setOS(String value) {
        this.os = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the osVrsn property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getOSVrsn() {
        return osVrsn;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the osVrsn property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setOSVrsn(String value) {
        this.osVrsn = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the device property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getDevice() {
        return device;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the device property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setDevice(String value) {
        this.device = value;
    }
}
```

I would like to know if i can change my script somehow, that makes my class fields have the same name that the `@XmlElement` has , for example the result would be:

```
    @XmlElement(name = "AppInstllCd")
    protected String AppInstllCd;
    @XmlElement(name = "AppVrsn")
    protected String AppVrsn;
    @XmlElement(name = "OS")
    protected String OS;
    @XmlElement(name = "OSVrsn")
    protected String OSVrsn;
    @XmlElement(name = "Device")
    protected String Device;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get around the naming convention used by JAXB. Some options, that I haven't personally tried myself would be following the accepted answer or the top voted answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267478/how-to-disable-java-naming-conventions-in-xjc).

---

Another option would be creating a XJC Plugin. Although that could be overkill. (I'm currently developing a XJC Plugin so I'm biased.)

[Tutorial that helped me getting started with XJC Plugins.](https://www.ricston.com/blog/xjc-plugin/)

The code of that Plugin could do something and almost look like this:

```
import com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin;

public class XJCPlugin extends Plugin {
    @Override
    public String getOptionName() { //... }

    @Override
    public int parseArgument(Options opt, String[] args, int i) throws BadCommandLineException, IOException {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean run(Outline model, Options opt, ErrorHandler errorHandler) throws SAXException {
        //...
    }
    @Override
    public void postProcessModel(Model model, ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        //This method changes the attribute names
        for (CClassInfo classInfo : model.beans().values()) //for each class
            for (CPropertyInfo propertyInfo : classInfo.getProperties()) //for each attribute
                propertyInfo.setName(false, Utility_StringHandling.firstCharacterToUpperCase(propertyInfo.getName(false)));
    }
    static String firstCharacterToUpperCase(String input) {
        char c[] = input.toCharArray();
        c[0] = Character.toUpperCase(c[0]);
        return new String(c);
    }
}
```